# Can I simplify spring configuration file beans by combining the annotations onto one method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I m making a @Configuration class that is to just provide the names of topics and queues I want to publish/subscribe to using JMS. The config file looks something like the following but repeated 10+ times.

```
@Value("myTopic")
private String myTopic;
@Bean("myTopic")
public String getMyTopic() { return this.myTopic; }
```

I was wondering if I could simplify it to the following. Whether it is best practice, allowed etc?

```
@Bean("myTopic")
public String getMyTopic(@Value("myTopic") final String myTopic) { return myTopic; }
```

I did not put the topics and queues inside application.properties, because this configuration class is being used by two different projects. If the values are put into application.properties, it would require both projects to include those values inside their application.properties, but I dont have access to change those

Comment: not too sure about this, but @Value inject the properties from somewhere, then wouldnt each call or reference to the myTopic bean or getMyTopic keep injecting the value making it less efficient?

Comment: Yes that will work, best practice (when using Spring Boot though) is to bind the properties to a properties class and inject that into the `@Bean` method. But what you wrote with the `@Bean` will just work.